# META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file not found in unnamed.war

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, manifest.mf, war

I am using Intellij idea and I want to deploy my project to the server. Before that I tried to create a .war file but when i create a war file, i am getting this error

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file not found in unnamed.war
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `MANIFEST.MF` to `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/web/src/main/webapp/META-INF/` folder with the [**simple content**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

Or you can generate it using [**IntelliJ Artifacts Configuring**](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-artifacts-layout-structure.html)